# Cambiar color seleccion lista Java Jframe

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo una lista y necesito marcar de color los usuarios mas importantes. Todo esto lo estoy haciendo en Netbeans.Tengo media solucion pero no es lo que quiero:

```
    public void cambiarColor(Color index1){
        listaClientes.setSelectionBackground(index1);
    }

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int selection = this.listaClientes.getSelectedIndex();
    
    if (selection!=-1){
        cambiarColor(Color.BLUE);
        
    
        }
    
    actualizarLista();
```

Esto marca toda la lista pero solo necesito que cambie el color de fondo de la row del usuario que marque, si cambio la variable selection me da error al pasar la propiedad SelectionBackground

Comment: ¿Y cómo saber cuales son los usuarios importantes? ¿Donde está definido?

Comment: Es solo una aplicacion de control de usuarios, pero necesito un boton para crear los usuarios , ya lo tengo pero necesito uno para marcar los mas importantes y por eso un boton para cambiar la row del usuario y no toda la lista

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente añadiendo otro `if`. Por ejemplo:

```
if (selection!=-1)

//En caso de que el usuario importante sea el de Index 5.
//Solo deberías cambiar la comprobación de ejemplo, por la que tengas.

    if (selection == 5)

        cambiarColor(Color.BLUE);
```

En caso de que necesites comprobar por nombre de usuario en lugar del index, reemplazas el `selection` por `listaClientes.getSelectedValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una clase que extienda de la clase `DefaultTableCellRenderer`   que renderiza las filas que deseas

```
class RowsRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        private int columna ;

        public RowsRenderer(int Colpatron)
        {
            this.columna = Colpatron;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column)
        {        
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            table.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);
           //comparamos que valor tendrá la columna que deseamos para pintar de color azul
          //En este caso estoy comparando que pintará los las filas donde se encuentre EJECUTIVO
            if(table.getValueAt(row,columna).equals("EJECUTIVO"))            
                this.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
           
            return this;
       }
}
```

Puedes llamar a la clase creada desde el método del botón

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   //supongamos que tu tabla se llama miTabla
   miTabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new RowsRenderer(13));
   //el número 13 es la cantidad de columnas que tiene tu tabla, esto lo cambias
 
}
```

Comment: Pero utilizo netbeans y ya estan creadas las funciones

Comment: @qwerty el código no depende del IDE, reemplaza tu método ``cambiarColor`` por la clase que te pasé